# Firebase token structure and storage

Tags: mysql, firebase, indexing, firebase-cloud-messaging

An FCM token is in the format of

```
fKk623mCfkm4:APA21bG2PqYzjxkwVElcODnMdTk9BP1AoNw-
rogg8uUdK9lzIc0Ow0KVa_19PRZE85v_0VZjBPBve4PAwqX9mVstr
o2fnzWoChgOVdIRU0YvOMRniOwg-KGB5EjajqD3Szl2lBwPZQBJ
```

Which is fairly long.

If one wants to store the token in MySQL and make sure that the token is unique, how would one go about doing that? I reckon the string is a bit too long to index. Is it reasonable to assume that the part before the colon (in this case `fKk623mCfkm4`) is unique within the scope of the application? If so this would be a much more reasonable way to index the token. (Just VARCHAR still, but with `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX fcm_token ON myTable myColumn(12)`)

I realize that that may be long shot, so: How would one solve this problem?

I am interested in the uniqueness of the token because a device might change owner (or user, for whatever reason) which would require that the token is reassigned in my database - but that's hard (irresponsible) if I cannot find it because it's not indexed.

<strike>A string of 12 alphanumeric characters may produce 5.906682292E37 different results. That kind of randomness seems like it would be enough to avoid a collision within a single application.</strike> Edit: Bad idea.

I am doing this currently:

```
CREATE TABLE `devices` (
 `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `USER` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `TOKEN` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `TOKENSHA1` binary(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `MODIFIED` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `TOKENSHA1` (`TOKENSHA1`),
 KEY `USER` (`USER`),
 KEY `MODIFIED` (`MODIFIED`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: It boils down whether the part before the colon is unique or not. If it is not, then you have to index the entire content.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't find any information on that anywhere. Was hoping maybe someone from FCM would know this.

Comment: Then this what you should ask.

Comment: I did ask that: "Is it reasonable to assume that the part before the colon (in this case fKk623mCfkm4) is unique within the scope of the application?" If someone knows this they could answer. I am just providing context as to *why* I need to know this :)

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I'm a bit confused. Are you asking if the FCM token (the complete value) is unique? Or simply the characters before the colon? I'm fairly sure that each token is unique, since it corresponds only to a specific device. It is recommended to store the token as it is, without cutting/modifying/adding any other characters to it.

Comment: I was planning on storing all of it, unmodified, and I am aware that the entire string is unique, but if the characters before the colon were too, there'd be no point in indexing more than the first 12 characters. That is the core of the question.

Answer (score 2):

That example string is not too long to index in MySql's Innodb engine.

MySQL's innodb engine has a maximum index key length of 767 bytes.

[MySql Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html)

If you want to index something that will enforce uniqueness, why not look for options that make no assumptions about the subsections of the token? Such options would include...

1. Just index the whole string (looks like 156 characters).
2. Index an sha1 hash of the string (40 hex digits) from mysql's sha1() function
3. Index a binary sha1 (20 bytes)
4. If it is base 64 encoded using a documented encoding, return it to its binary form and index that.

It does not seem wise to make assumptions about the part before the : unless the existence and purpose of this part are documented. Even if it works now you can't be sure it will work every time in the future. There's a good chance that this token is either a base 64 encoded public key, or cryptographic hash, or that it is something like a jwt whose contents may change in the future.

Firebase documentation that I have read presents this token as simply a token, with no explanation of its content. It looks base64 encoded, but I have not seen that documented.

Comment: I am aware that it's not *too* long, but performance wise I figured it might not be a great idea. Perhaps I'm overthinking it. I think I found a way to avoid having a unique index anyway. Your suggestions with hashing are good! I'll consider :)

Answer (score 1):

*Note to other readers:  This answer assumes that the only purpose for the table is to catch dups.  This assumption turns out not to be correct.*

How big is your table?  Let's say you have 1 million rows.  That index (n its own BTree) would take about 250MB on disk.  How much RAM do you have?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  They are probably big enough to afford some effort at caching the 250MB.  If you don't need to test more than 100 tokens per second, even if you have to hit disk, it should not be a problem.  100 inserts/sec would add up to 8M rows per day.

It looks like the token is ascii, so be sure to specify the charset, something like

```
FCM VARCHAR(156) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL
```

Do not do `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ... myColumn(12)` - that will store the entire 156 characters, but check only 12 for uniqueness.  It is a virtually useless feature, and is often the "wrong" thing to do.

**Plans A, B, C**

*If* the only purpose is to check whether the 156-char string has already be seen...

Plan A:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
    fcm CHAR(156) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(fcm)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

0 copies of ID (0 bytes)
0 copy of SHA1 (0)
1 copy of TOKEN (156 bytes, assuming ascii)

Total: 156 bytes (plus overhead)

Plan B:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
    digest BINARY(16) NOT NULL, -- MD5(fcm)
    PRIMARY KEY(digest)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

0 copies of ID (0 bytes)
1 copy of MD5 (16 bytes)
0 copies of TOKEN (0 bytes)

Total: 16 bytes

Either of these Plans has *one* BTree.  Either will very quickly test for a single dup.  Either will touch only one block when you `INSERT` a new row.

Plan A will take more space than Plan B.  Some are concerned about accidental dups in digests (MD5, SHA1, etc), and would shun Plan B, otherwise I would not have included Plan A at all.

Either Plan will eventually slow down -- This will happen when the table grows so big that it cannot be cached in RAM.  When the table is 20 times as big as cache, only 1/20th of the lookups will find the record in RAM.  Plan A, being bigger will start to slow down sooner.

Plan C:  Putting *both* the 156 and 16 in the table makes for a bigger table.  Hence you get to the slowdown sooner (than at least one of A or B), regardless of how it is indexed.

```
PRIMARY KEY(md5)
```

0 copies of ID (0 bytes)
1 copy of md5 (16 bytes)
1 copy of TOKEN (156 bytes, assuming ascii)

Total: 172 bytes

**After adding more columns and indexes**

Plan D (by nickdnk):

```
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
UNIQUE KEY `TOKENSHA1` (`TOKENSHA1`),
KEY `USER` (`USER`),
KEY `MODIFIED` (`MODIFIED`)
```

4 copies of ID (4*4 bytes)
2 copies of SHA1 (2*20 bytes, assuming BINARY(20), not VARCHAR)
1 copy of TOKEN (156 bytes, assuming ascii)

Total: 212 bytes (plus overhead)

Plan E:

```
PRIMARY KEY(TOKEN),
INDEX(USER),
INDEX(MODIFIED)
```

0 copies of ID (0 bytes)
0 copies of SHA1 (0 bytes)
3 copies of TOKEN (3*156 bytes, assuming ascii)

Total: 468 bytes

Plan F:

```
PRIMARY KEY(TOKENSHA1),
INDEX(USER),
INDEX(MODIFIED)
```

0 copies of ID (0 bytes)
3 copy of SHA1 (3*20 bytes)
1 copy of TOKEN (156 bytes, assuming ascii)

Total: 216 bytes

So, Your Plan (D) is good, especially if you need more indexes.  My Plan F is essentially as good.  (The 4 byte loss is compensated for by overhead.)

`INSERTs` are slowed down some by having to check two `UNIQUE` keys.  `SELECTs` *may* encounter performance differences.

Comment: I ended up doing a SHA1 hash of the token and then indexing that in a binary(20) field using UNHEX. I think that solution gives me what I want: Auto-incrementing primary key and a compact unique index to identify tokens, while still keeping the actual tokens in storage in full length (varchar 255, *without* index).

Comment: I suggest that the SHA1 is not worth the extra hassle.  A 1-column InnoDB table with a 156-char `PRIMARY KEY` is _smaller_ than that _plus_ a column and index on a 20-byte sha1.

Comment: But a primary key of random data is not a great idea in the long run, as I understand. Such as like here: http://kccoder.com/mysql/uuid-vs-int-insert-performance/ - and that's only with uuid which is just 16 characters, not 156 characters. The idea is to maintain speed and prevent fragmentation by using the AI PK + secondary index.

Comment: Haha. We actually discussed something very similar a few years back, I just noticed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28084901/how-does-mysql-determine-if-an-insert-is-unique/28547410#28547410 - And you said "PRIMARY KEY(UUID)... Since the UUID is very random, the "next" row you INSERT will be located at a 'random' spot. If the table is much bigger than be cached in the buffer_pool, the block the new row needs to go into is very likely to not be cached. This leads to a disk hit to pull the block into cache (the buffer pool), and eventually another disk hit to write it back to disk."

Comment: But...  The index with the UUID (or 156-char string) becomes the "very random" BTree that you are inserting into.  It's a tradeoff; hard to say which will be better.

Comment: Yeah - but my point is then that a random insert into an unclustered 20-byte index should be less work than a clustered 156-byte index, no? I'm not indexing the full token at all, only the hashed version. Don't care so much about storage space, mainly RAM / buffer pool :)

Comment: An index has the same structure as a table (in InnoDB) -- a BTree with something "clustered" to give it the ordering.  Hence, the UUID is "clustered" in the INDEX BTree -- same "random" problem, just 20/156th the size.

Comment: If you store _only_ the MD5, and do _not_ store or check the 156, then you can get away with a 16-byte-wide table (again with a clustered index).  Pack it into `BINARY(16)`.

Comment: I could, but I need to store the token also. I need it in its original format. I am packing the SHA1 hash into a binary(16) :) The "20/156th of the size" was the idea behind this choice. And I guess I still haven't understood the clustered concept then. I was under the impression that the PK had more impact on performance than secondary indexes.

Comment: Added more details to my answer.  Also, `SHA1` needs `BINARY(20)`.  (`MD5` needs only 16.)

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant binary(20) for sha1. With plan C, wouldn't that only be true if the primary key is the FCM? I am using INT(11) AI for PK and BINARY(20) hashed token secondary index, but no index on the original FCM column.

Comment: Oh, I did not take into consideration `user` and `modified`.

Comment: Well they weren't really related to the question anyway. They have to be there for foreign key purposes and finding tokens of a specific age.

Comment: Very much related.  I assumed you needed to do nothing by check for dups.  Adding more columns _and more indexes_ throws all of my comments into question.

Comment: I don't see how that changes the original issue? I still need to be able to find the tokens, get their original data and not insert duplicates. A user may have many devices (FCM tokens) but a device may only belong to one user. How would you do it?

Comment: Okay, so I'm good actually. But why is plan D storing 2 copies of the hashed token? Edit: And the problem with plan F is that the original token is lost.

Comment: One copy in the data, one copy in the `UNIQUE` key.

Comment: B,F:  If you trust the has to be 1:1 with the token, and you don't need to fetch the actual token, then the token suffices for uniqueness check.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand that last comment. "If my trust the has to be 1:1 with the token"?

Comment: If two strings are different, then the SHA1 of the strings will be different.  There is only an infinitesimally tiny change that the digests will accidentally be the same.